# How did this get closed as a duplicate of a completely different question?

Tags: discussion

This question: [What items look like scrappable junk, but aren't?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/251020/108003), was somehow closed as a duplicate of this question: [Is there any scrappable junk I should hold on to that could otherwise be used for other purposes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243883/108003)

It should be clear from the titles that those aren't even similar, but let me explain a little further anyway. The first one asks for things that *aren't* scrappable junk. The second one asks for things that *are*. The first one is about *not* picking things up. The second is about *holding onto* things. The first one's answer contains mostly *useless* things. The second is specifically about things that *have a use*.

These are *totally* different.

What the heck happened here? Can we get some reopen votes?

Comment: It was probably just a mistake. I can see why people would think they're duplicates, especially if they're concentrating on the titles. In particular, as someone who doesn't play Fallout 4, I initially read your question's title as  meaning "What items look like scrappable junk, but aren't [actually junk]?", which make the two questions seem very related.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Maybe that was it. I'll ask if anybody has a better title idea.

Comment: I voted that as dupe too, I thought that it was the same question, guess I should really play FO4. Sorry for that, and I voted it for reopening.

Comment: My bad. I was in the review queue, I didn't see the differences until now

Comment: @Robotnik These things happen. Would you say that new title makes the difference clearer?

Comment: @DCShannon - yep definitely.